# Should I do the stateful matching with iptables for nat table?

Tags: iptables, firewall, router, nat, nf-conntrack

I often see that there are some stateful matching rules in a iptables' chain such as INPUT.

I known what they are doing, and I'm interested in that

> Should I do the same for the chains of the table NAT?

For example, in my home router, I want it accepts ssh, and also acts as a NAT router.

If we have:

`-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

`-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`

should I do follows for better performance?

`-t nat -A POSTROUTING -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j MASQUERADE`

`-t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o wan0 -m state --state NEW -j MASQUERADE`

I guess that I should **NOT** do the same for the POSTROUTING chain, but **should** for the FORWARD.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need that.

Dynamic NAT rules always use conntrack tables. So this is useless (and wrong). The `nat` table is traversed only by *first* packet of the connection, so it'll only see `--ctstate NEW` packets. It never sees `--ctstate ESTABLISHED` packets, because these don't traverse rules. If the packet is found in the connection tracker nat table, it has the recorded translation applied and proceed with next table.

Connection state consideration appears to be useful in the `FORWARD` chain, not in the `PREROUTING` or `POSTROUTING`, so use it in the `FORWARD filter` or `FORWARD mangle` tables.

Additional note: `state` match module is obsolete and removed from the kernel. Actual match is implemented with the `conntrack` module. In my opinion, it is better to use it explicitely, so better always use `-m conntrack --ctstate ...` rather that `-m state`.